# Call PostgreSQL functions from JPA return void array

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get a Resultset from a Postgres sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "core"."tablesync"("_parameter" varchar)
RETURNS TABLE("id" int4, "par_type" int4, "parent" int4, "name" varchar, "par_value" varchar,    "category" int4) AS $BODY$ 
     
                                select prm.id,prm.par_type,prm.parent,prm.name,prm.par_value,prm.category from parameter prm
                                where par_type = _parameter::int;
                                --select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3 from table a
              --join table2 as b on a.col1 = b.col1;
    $BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE
COST 100
ROWS 1000
```

When that function is executed from sql query the following result is returned:

[image]

Then I need to get same result in java with code below:

```
 @Repository
public class SyncRepositoryImpl implements SyncRepository {

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public ArrayList syncTable(JsonNode model) {
    ArrayList dataSync = (ArrayList)entityManager.createNativeQuery("select  * from core.tablesync('8')").getResultList();
    return dataSync;
}
```

But in debug mode shows me that is void array. Any idea what is happening?.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specify scheema in sql code and it works